# Cascade amplifiers with different corner frequency

Tags: amplifier, cutoff-frequency

In these 2 cases I have the output of a non inversor circuit connected to the input of an inversor circuit. The only difference is the resistors. What I have noticed is that the cutoff frequency is different for both cases, but I dont know why, since both separate circuits have the same cutoff frequency and gain. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The first op amp is driving more current to ground than the second one...

Comment: When you say "both separate circuits have the same cutoff frequency and gain", do you mean the op amps by themselves, or the inverting and non-inverting amplifier sections?

Comment: I mean the inverting and non inverting. The separate cascade circuits have different gains and cutoff frequencies. And thats what I dont understand

Comment: Might be a loading effect: the input resistance of the inverting amplifier (the last stage) is basically the resistor you put in the front. So, in one case your first stage is driving a 100 ohm load, in the other the first stage is driving a 1kohm load. Put a middle stage made of an ampli in follower configuration to decouple the stages, and see if you get the same result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> *What I have noticed is that the cutoff frequency is different for both
>   cases, but I dont know why, since both separate circuits have the same
>   cutoff frequency and gain.*

They certainly don't have the same gain. The non-inverting stage has a gain of: -

$$1 + \dfrac{1400}{100} = 15$$

The inverting stage has a gain magnitude of: -

$$\dfrac{2000}{100} = 20$$

Based on this, they are bound to have different cut-off frequencies. Here's why (using a typical bode plot from an op-amp): -

[image]

- At a gain of 20, the 3 dB point will be 430 kHz
- At a gain of 15, the 3 dB point will be 630 kHz

OK it's a different op-amp to the LM324 but the principle is the same; the lower gain setup will have a cut-off frequency that is circa 63/43 higher than the higher gain setup.

Comment: What I meant is that the cuttoff frequency of the cascade amplifiers is different. And I dont know why.

Comment: Is different to what? Given that I've shown you the mechanism involved - can you see why now?

Comment: I posted two different cascade amplifers. And each one of them as a different cutoff frequency.

Comment: But, can you now see why? Inverting gain and non-inverting gains are different for the same resistors and hence, their respective cut-off frequencies will be different. Non inverting gain = \$1 + \dfrac{R_F}{R_G}\$ but inverting gain is simply \$\dfrac{R_F}{R_G}\$

Comment: That part I understood. But in both cases the non inverting and inverting gains and cutoff frequencies are the same, however in cascade i notice a diference in the cutoff frequency from the first circuit i showed and the second. The only difference is that all resistors are multiplied by 10 from one to the other. Is that the reason why?

Comment: @Catarina it certainly could come down to using higher value resistors - what numbers did you get for both circuits regarding cut-off frequencies?

Comment: The one with all the resistors multiplied by 10:
      - Non inverting: 38kHz
      - Inverting: 28kHz
      - Cascade: 38kHz

The other one:
      - Non inverting: 38kHz
      - Inverting: 28kHz
      - Cascade: 28kHz

Comment: Well something is wrong because the inverting stage having a cut-off of 28 kHz should be dominant and make the combined cascade around 28 kHz also (not 38 kHz). Are you working with breadboard by any chance?

Comment: No, I am only working with this simulation using TINA, and these are the results I got.

Answer (score 0):

Each amplifier should have some gain bandwidth product.
The first amplifier stage has a gain of 14 and the second stage has a gain of 20.

Therefore I would expect that the cutoff frequency for the second amplifier would be lower.  The value should be 14/20 * the_cutoff_of_the_first_amplifier.

Real op-amps have parasitic capacitance's at their terminals (usually in the pF range).  The combination of the feedback resistors and that parasitic capacitance can create a low pass filter with some cutoff.  If the resistors are large enough it can reduce your cutoff frequency or lead to instability in the feedback.

On the other hand, the ability of an op-amp output-stage to drive current usually decreases with frequency.  So if the feedback resistors are too small then it will also lead to a reduction in cutoff frequency.  It looks like that is the case here.

Even though the resistor ratios are similar in the two designs, the resistor values are different by a factor of 10 so I would expect some change due to that.

Comment: What doesn't makes sense to me is that the cuttoff frequency on the circuit with all the resistors multiplied by 10 is about 38kHz. The cutoff frequency for the non inverting and inverting are about 38kHz and 28kHz respectively. Shouldn't I expect the cutoff frequency of the cascade be about 28khz? Because thats what happens on the other circuit i showed.

Answer (score 0):

The results you should get are:

Non inverting: fc = 66.7kHz (from 1MHz/15)

Inverting: fc = 47.6kHz (from 1MHz/21)

Cascade: fc = 37kHz.

1MHz is the GBW of the LM324.

Your two simulations show that you are getting fc = 37kHz (nominal) for both cascades, although the two results are slightly different due to the different loading on the op amps' outputs.

Comment: Weirdly the results I got are quite different from what you said. What I got was:
The one with all the resistors multiplied by 10: - Non inverting: 38kHz - Inverting: 28kHz - Cascade: 38kHz 
The other one: - Non inverting: 38kHz - Inverting: 28kHz - Cascade: 28kHz